# Ireport Default Parameter value Expression

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report consisting of two parameters

> 1. Start_Date
> 2. End_Date
>
> I want to write an expression in Ireport where the parameter Start_Date display first day of the year (2018-01-01) by default as parameter value
>
> Example today's date 2018-10-18 I want the parameter Start_Date to have this default value as 2018-01-01
>
> Is there any expression in Ireport which can display 2018-01-01 as default value. (First Day of Year)

Answer (score 0):

Set the Default Value expression of your Start_Date parameter field to this:

```
"01.01." +  java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
```

It sucessfully generated a report for me.

The same should work for your other parameter, e.g. with the last day of the year.